# Use Dynamic value for "Use [database]"

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem about "Use [database]". I made procedure like below.

```
    USE [DBtemp1]
    
    Select *
    from [DBtemp1].[Schemas].table
```

But, there 10 databases (DBtemp1 ~ DBtemp10), so there are 10 procedures and I want to integrate procedures.

And I found it, like below

```
    SET @DBName = 'DBtemp1'
    
    SET @strQry = ' USE ' + @DBName + '; select * from [Schemas].table'
    EXECUTE (@strQry )
```

But my procedure have many joins, so it is little complex

I want to use it like below. but it is not work.

```
    Declare @DBName = 'DBtemp1'
    
    select count(*) from @DBName.[Schemas].table
```

Is there a similar way?

Comment: Dynamic SQL (as you have tried for the simple case) is the only way. PS by "Schems" you mean "database" right?

Comment: @juergend OP want's to `USE` this only works with database name, not schema name.

Comment: There are DBMS products where "schema" and "database" mean the same thing, but in SQL Server they are different. A database can contain many schemas. In your question you have referenced `tempdb`, which is a *database*, and your names start with "DB", which suggests "database" to me, but then your example shows a 2 part name: `@DBName.tbl`. In a 2 part name, the name is of the form `[schema].[table]`. If you wanted to refer to database, it would be a 3 part name: `[database].[schema].[table]`. There is a way to write your queries without dynamic SQL *if* you can live with serialized execution.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. maybe [database] is right. i can use it [IP Address].[database].[table].. so i want "use [database]".

Comment: There is somewhat of a mixup here. As Preben Huybrechts wrote - `USE x` only works if x is a database, however as allmhuran wrote, `select ... from x.y` only works if x is a schema - and those are two different concepts in SQL Server. Please [edit] your question to remove the contradicting examples and clarify your problem. Thanks

Comment: @Dale K. Thank you for reply. that is very sad... it is very complex :(. i need consider that "manage 10 procedures" vs "Complex 1 procedure"

Comment: Good database design would normally involving managing 10 procedures IMHO. I know its not how one normally codes in other languages, but T-SQL is not designed for any form of generic coding. One normally does create multiple procedures to do this sort of thing. Some people do go the dynamic SQL route, but personally I find that brings more issues than it solves - unless its for a specific situation where I can test it properly and its unlikely to need to change in future.

Comment: @Dale K. Thank you for your deep insight. i made question because the Postgre-SQL can manage it One procedure. and my procedure often changes. at that time i need change 10 procedures. i feel it is waste time. :(

Comment: @H.YK SQL Server table name identifiers contains the following parts: `[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]` Valid identifiers are: `[Table]`, `[Schema].[Table]`, `[Database].[Schema].[Table]`, `[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`, `[Database]..[Table]` (Note the double dot between these two!) or `[Server].[Database]..[Table]` (again with the double dot between database and table. A missing schema name means using the login's default schema.

Comment: If all the databases are the same, it *might* indicate a problem in the server's design... Why do you have multiple databases with the same structure in the first place?

Comment: @Zohar Peled. Thank you for your kindly reply. then... finaly If it work. what temp is it? `select * from [temp].table` and also `use [temp]` and.. maybe you are right.. when i join this project. the design is already consist like it. and this project is started in 2015. so there are many applications based on this database.. so now it can't fix..

Comment: If something like that works in PostgreSQL, then it's highly likely you are using **schemas** there, not databases (as you can't change the current database inside a stored procedure or function). So you should use schemas as well in SQL Server if you want a similar setup

Comment: It's possible to use the name the database as well as a schema within that databaes - so you have `temp01` as the database name and in there `temp01` as a schema in that database - possible, conceivable, but not really a good idea. However, if it's a 5 years old  system it might be too much work to change now... In SQL Server, you can address different databases and even different servers inside a single procedure - using a 3 or 4 parts table identifier as I've written in one of the previous comments - but you can't use the `USE DbName;` inside a stored procedure (or a function)

Comment: @Zohar Peled. I try to find `[Schema]`. Finally, i completed all the query you explained. Thank you. i was wrong. `select * from [temp].table` doesn't work. i made `select * from [Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]` and In procedure. there is `use [Database]` and use like it `from [Schema].[Table]` So... you means, as a result, there is no way to integrate in one procedure.. is it right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thank you for reply. It was a confusing concepts. but Zohar Peled helped me. and i can understand what you say. (Just what you say, still don't know how it work..) but, you give me a direction so i will study it. Again thank you.

Comment: You can use a single procedure - but you will have to use dynamic SQL for that. The choice here is either a single procedure with dynamic SQL, or maintaining a copy of the procedure in each database.

Comment: @Zohar Peled. Thank you. today i learned a lot from you. and i edit my question (in my point of view, it is clear) Have a nice day~

Comment: You can't parameterize Identifiers in SQL. Parameters are placeholders for data, identifiers are not data. Your only option for a single procedure is using dynamic SQL.